# Google drive save to not working (Google drive api)

Tags: html, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to make a website that will save a cat into the account of the user and have tried this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="http://example.com/pug-snores.mp3"
   data-filename="pug-snores.mp3"
   data-sitename="A Snoring Pug">
</div>
```

The save icon shows up but it does not save to the drive.

Why?

Thanks

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive#cors

Comment: otherwise there is something wrong with the filepath - that will also cause this error

Comment: It still doesn't work address = http://samrobbins.125mb.com/googledrive.html

Comment: the problem may be that it's over 2mb refer to the docs try it with a smaller file

Comment: the server needs to allow cors - see edited answer

Comment: Now it is giving me: Failed Upload HTTP error (6)

Comment: sorry i was having my dinner share the link again

Comment: what are the permissions of the file set to in your server for the file ? they should be 777 to share

Comment: http error 6 is could not resolve host name - check the domain is not down and check your internet connection your server may be down

Answer (score 1):

try the explicit render: code from the [google javascript api](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive#javascript_api)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Explicit Render</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
      {parsetags: 'explicit'}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="render-link">Render the Save to Drive button</a>
    <div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
    <script>
      function renderSaveToDrive() {
        gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', {
          src: '//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf',
          filename: 'My Statement.pdf',
          sitename: 'My Company Name'
        });
      }
      document.getElementById('render-link').addEventListener('click', renderSaveToDrive);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data-src URL can be served from another domain but the responses from the HTTP server needs to support HTTP OPTION requests and include the following special HTTP headers:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
```

Comment: What do I need to put in the example.com near the top?

Comment: @Sam your own web address

Comment: @Sam are you signed into Google?

Comment: @Sam yes the hosted address

Answer (score 1):

If you want upload a local file with input file form and/or without php lib would be ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Explicit Render</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="GDrive" name="GDrive" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "post">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onChange="renderSaveToDrive('savetodrive-div', this.files[0].name,'GDrive');"><div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function renderSaveToDrive(namediv, namefile, idfrm) {
            window.___gcfg = {
                lang: 'es-ES',
                parsetags: 'explicit'
            };
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem(idfrm));
            fd.append("file_new_name", namefile);
            xhr.open("POST", location.href);
            xhr.send(fd);       
            gapi.savetodrive.render(namediv, {
              src: namefile,
              filename: namefile,
              sitename: 'GDrive Demo: Explicit Render'
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```